# Pattern 'components/*/*' can have at most one '*' character

Tags: typescript, react-native, import

I am working on a React Native application with Expo, and I am using some template components from 3rd party.
In my src directory, I have an "app" folder that holds my components to use.
[This is the app folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWbe3.png)

[And this is the whole folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmEpB.png)

Almost every component is also structured in this way:
[Example of Button component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcBMU.png)

My tsconfig.json file is giving me problems, since I needed to change some paths as well:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react-native",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "components/*": ["./app/components"],
            "components/*/*": ["./app/components/*/index"],
            "services/*": ["./app/services"],
            "app/*": ["./app"],
            "navigation/*": ["./app/navigation"],
            "theme/*": ["./app/theme/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

And it's complaining about that

```
Pattern 'components/*/*' can have at most one '*' character.
```

When I try to import a Button component into my page Register.tsx, this is what React native is complaining about:

```
Unable to resolve "components/atoms/text" from "app/components/atoms/button/index.js"
```

I am trying every solution to fix this but it doesn't work. I tried to manually change every import but this is not an option that could work, is extremely time consuming and it won't make any sense.

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But if you are trying to import index.js from the button folder, then you this is how it should be;

```
import index.js from '../app/components/atoms/button
```

Comment: The problem is in tsconfig file. 
this line
```
"components/*/*": ["./app/components/*/index"],
```
is giving me this error: 
Pattern 'components/*/*' can have at most one '*' character

Comment: And this solution is not suitable for me because I would need to change the import of every single file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if you haven't got a solution try this pattern

```
components/**/*.js|ts
```